# front end view files from directory and delete on click

Tags: php, html, file, upload, directory

I have a php page on my site for admin use, that let's me upload files to a directory. I also have it set up to show me a list of files in the directory, right now the list looks like so -

- .
- ..
- audio.mp3
- audio2.mp3
- amazon_polly_2813.mp3

Now I am trying to do 2 things- 
1. Remove the ".", ".." from my list.
2. Let users click on the button next to the file to delete it.

My code currently --

```
<?php
$dir    = '/uploads/music';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

if(count($files1) > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $files1) . '</li>';
    echo '<a href="?delete=1">delete</a>';
 if(isset($_GET['delete']))
    {
        unlink($files1);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

I was able to get the "."/".." out the list -

```
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$musicfiles = array_diff($files1, array('.', '..'));
```

but I'm still having issues deleting the file.

**EDIT 2**

I changed my code a little bit and I think I'm getting closer. Right now the delete button is deleting all the files instead of a single one --

```
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

<?php
$dir    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/uploads/music';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$musicfiles = array_diff($files1, array('.', '..'));

echo '<ul>';

if(count($musicfiles) > 0) {
foreach ($musicfiles as $mf) {

$mfclean = str_replace(".mp3","",$mf);
$ifile = '/wp-content/uploads/music/'.$mf;

echo '<li>'.ucfirst($mfclean).' <a href="'.unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$ifile).'">x</a></li>';

      }
   }

echo '</ul>';

?>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your `unlink`?

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski yes, the unlink doesnt work

Comment: What error is `unlink` giving you?

Comment: One problem I noticed is that you're passing `$files1`, an array, to `unlink`. Unlink only accepts `strings`. So if you want to delete all the files in that directory you will have to `explode($files1)` and call `unlink` on each element of the resulting array.